# How to add spacing in static text or how to setting character spacing

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using iReport 5.5. I put the static text, in preview the text is showing perfect, but in my output printing the character spacing is not normal.

[image: this is the preview image]

This is the output printing image:

[image: and this is the output printing image]

I set the text to stretch but without positive changes

This is example of my static text:

```
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="192" y="24" width="152" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="d7aedc6e-1158-4aee-b3f5-32ec446fb9d7"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Monospaced" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[MUHAMAD KHOIRUL UMAM]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
```

Comment: Did you try to change the font? Are you using the  Font Extensions?

Comment: yes i was try to change the font ..
and font size.
in my preview the text was changed and perfectly ..
but no effect in my output print ..
i using the monospaced font default font from netbeans.

Comment: and what about font-extensions? did you add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's solved after trying run the project in other computer. in windows 10 64bit,. i don't know why .. but it's running perfectly :D